# How to get FCM token for the device that don't have Google play services in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created an Android app in which I am using Firebase cloud messaging to send push notifications to the device. I have two devices, one have updated google play services (device A) but the other one don't (device B).

I am able to get the FCM token for device A and send the notifications successfully.
When I try to get the FCM token for device B then I received the following error message:
java.io.IOException: MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE

I have tried to side load Google play services but it didn't work.
I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution.

**I really need to get the FCM token for Device B**

This is how I am getting the FCM token

```
   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
       .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult> () {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("cloudMessage", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
            }else if(task.isSuccessful ()) {
                try {
                    // Get new Instance ID token
                    String token = task.getResult ().getToken ();
                    // Log and toast
                    Log.d ( "cloudMessage", "Token: " + token );
                }catch (Exception ex){

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to use FCM on devices without Play services.  Play services not only gives you the device token, but it also handles the receipt of messages and delivers them to your app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other way to send push notifications to such devices? third party library/API etc? I have found some like [Blueshift](https://developer.blueshift.com/docs/setup-blueshifts-android-sdk) , [Braze](https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/android/push_notifications/integration/#registering-for-push) , [Pusher](https://pusher.com/tutorials/push-notifications-android) . but they are also using FCM

Comment: What I am trying to implement is [Google calendar push notification](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push) in the app. I have created a web-hook callback receiver where google is sending the notifications, I just need to **send the notification to the device** so it can fetch the events.

Comment: Recommendations for products are off topic for Stack Overflow.  Do a web search to find alternatives.